# Feasibility of dual programs

Tags: duality-theorems, constraint-programming

I am having trouble understanding the feasibility of dual programs. I am new in this topic and some help would be greatly appreciated :))

For example , here i have two problems in duality :

The primal (P) which is

max 1 + 32

1 + 22≤ 7

x≥0

and the dual (D) which is

min 7

≥1

2≥3

≥0.

On the answer sheet it states that x=(0,0) fulfills the constraints of the primal problem and =2 satisfies the dual constraint, so both problems are feasible.

Couldn't y=3 satisfy the dual constraint ?

I do not really understand this answer. Where are the x=(0,0) and the =2 coming from and how are they linked to feasibility ?

Thanks for the help guys !

Comment: $_1 + 2_2$  is not a constraint. Please check it!

Comment: Yes $y=3$ satisfies the dual constraints, and so does any number $\ge\frac32.$  To show feasibility, you only have to give one example that satisfies the constraints; there will typically be infinitely many.

Comment: I think the constraint supposed to be $x_1+2x_2\leq 7$

Comment: Yes ! sorry for the mistake....

Comment: where is the x=(0,0) coming from ?

Comment: @SaraSalvante We don´t know what the lecturer wanted to show. Can you post the corresponding question word by word?

Comment: "Consider the primal problem and the dual problem. Show that both problems have feasible solutions"

Comment: @SaraSalvante In this case you are free to choose values which satisfy the corresponding constraints. $x=(1,1);y=8$ is another feasible solution. And yes, $y=3$ is valid as well.